# Creating new Python Script tool with ArcGIS Notebooks

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, jupyter-notebook, arcgis-notebook

I am trying to create a new tool in ArcGIS Pro that is based on a python script written in the Jupyter Notebook interface. I realize I can write the script elsewhere and save it as a *.py file and point the new tool to it, or simply convert the *.ipynb file into a *.py file (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file), for example). But these methods force me to have a *.py file for every script I write in Notebooks.

Is there a way to link the new tool directly to the *.ipynb file?

Comment: No, if you want a *script* tool, you need to save your code as a script not a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to test the script only in the notebook. If it runs without errors you can save it with a simple editor as *.py and include it in a toolbox. I am not aware that you can save a script from the ArcGIS Pro Notebook.

You can only add the script as a Python script. Any other format is not supported.